# Issue tracker with custom front end app

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, list

I would like to have an issue tracker list but I don't want anyone (besides admins) to be able to view that list. I would like to create a custom front end so that when a user logs in, they are presented with only the tickets they have created.

When an admin logs in they see the entire list and can do the normal assigning of tickets etc.

Is there a resource anywhere explaining how to do this? I cant be the only one that has needed this functionality.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Item Level Permissions functionality is not available on “Issue Tracking” list (not custom list). As its default WriteSecurity is 1 and can't be changed. An issues list is based on the content type called "Issue".  This is by design.

Comment: Hi, I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? 

If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.